# Send Data from Child Component To Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey there I'm trying to send a todoValue from the child to the parent component,
Currently when I run this code I get an error saying: "TypeError: this.props.addNewTodo is not a function" Any suggestions/fixes?

Thanks CasperTheGhost

my Code:

**Parent Component**

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      todos: []
    }
  }

  addNewTodo = (newTodo) => {
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo]
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <AddTodo newTodo={this.addNewTodo} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}/
```

**Child Component**

```js
class AddTodo extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super() 

        this.state = {
            todoValue: ""
        }
    }

    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const todo = this.state.todoValue;
        this.props.addNewTodo(todo)
    }

    handleTodoValue = (event) => {
        this.setState({todoValue: event.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <FormControl>
                <InputLabel>What Are Going Todo</InputLabel>
                <Input id="todo" value={this.state.todoValue} onChange={this.handleTodoValue}  required/>

            {/* <Button>Add Todo</Button> */}
            </FormControl>
            </form>
        );
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props name was different from calling name.That props name was `newTodo` .So use `newTodo` instead of `addNewTodo`

```
 onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const todo = this.state.todoValue;
        this.props.newTodo(todo)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shuold use Redux or React Context:(https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)